# Salva o estado ou os cookies do navegador utilizando o selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo testes utilizando o whatsapp web, então todas as vezes eu executo o selenium, leio o qr code e inicio os testes, e eu tenho que fazer isso todas as vezes, eu gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de salvar o estado do navegador, salvar a sessão, alguma maneira de iniciar o browser sem a necessidade de ler o qr code novamente.

Estou utilizando o python para isso.

Tentei desta forma, mas não consigo salvar os cookies:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver

Salvando o arquivo:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

Recuperando o arquivo:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Utilizo o pprint para mostrar o driver.get_cookies() e ele retorna um array vazio, pensei que podia ser porque ele pega antes de carregar os cookies,mas ai coloquei em um while que enquanto o array estivesse vazio ele iria tentar e tentar mas mesmo assim, ele só pega o array vazio.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

dir_path = os.getcwd()
profile = os.path.join(dir_path, "profile", "wpp")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(
    r"user-data-dir={}".format(profile))

browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
```

estava com esse msm problema e resolvi dessa forma. Você só precisa logar uma vez, dps ele entra sem precisar scannear o QR Code dnv

Comment: Na versão atual do selenium não precisa colocar o endereço do executável e ainda a variável ````options```` é que deve ser colocada. Assim funcionou certinho, parabéns!

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução que se aproxima do que você precisa realizar e de uma forma escalável seria utilizar uma técnica de hack chamada [Phishing](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing), encontrei um projeto que utiliza Selenium, Node.js e Sockets.io.

[GitHub: Whatsapp Phishing](https://github.com/Mawalu/whatsapp-phishing)

Eu testei e funciona, acredito que consiga usar este projeto como base para solucionar sua questão, pois captura as informações de autenticação do web.whatsapp.