# Tenho que fazer login toda vez que rodo um robô com Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testes-automatizados

alguém sabe como eu consigo fazer com que um robô faça login apenas uma vez na Binomo e depois, caso eu o rode novamente, ele não precise fazer isso?

Estou usando selenium para acessar o site da Binomo, preencher o formulário e acessar a plataforma.
As vezes ele não pede um captcha, mas as vezes pede.

Existe uma maneira de deixar ele persistente(não sei se esse seria o termo)?

Este é o meu código (sou novo no python)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

linkDeAcesso = 'https://binomo.com/trading'

option1 = Options()
option1.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=option1)
browser.get(linkDeAcesso)

time.sleep(2)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qa_auth_LoginEmailInput"]/vui-input/div[1]/div[1]/vui-input-text/input').send_keys("e-mail")
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qa_auth_LoginPasswordInput"]/vui-input/div[1]/div[1]/vui-input-password/input').send_keys("senha")
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qa_auth_LoginBtn"]/button').click()

time.sleep(10)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="asset-0"]/button').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qa_trading_dealTimeInput"]/div[1]/div[1]/vui-input-number/input').click()

textoAlternativo = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qa_trading_dealTimeInput"]/div[1]/vui-popover/div[2]/lib-platform-scroll/div/div/div/div[1]/vui-option[5]').text
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qa_trading_dealTimeInput"]/div[1]/vui-popover/div[2]/lib-platform-scroll/div/div/div/div[1]/vui-option[5]').click()
conta = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="account-btn"]/div/p[1]').text

time.sleep(2)

if conta == 'Conta demo':
    print('Conta demo')
else:
    print('Conta Real')
```

Ele tem que seguir os passos:

- Abrir o navegador
- Acessar o site da Binomo
- Preencher o formulário com usuário e senha
- Clicar no botão de entrar (problema este que as vezes é apresentado um capctha)
- Ao acessar a plataforma, ele deve escolher o tempo de 5 minutos e os pares "Crypto IDX"

Problema é toda vez ele abrir o navegador e ter que preencher novamente o login.

Comment: Olá na plataforma da Binomo não é permitido o uso de robôs ou qualquer outro procedimento automatizado, a conta pode ser bloqueada.

Answer (score -1):

Com o selenium coloca ele para pegar um perfil de usuario para que o cache fique salvo

```py
from Selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #acminho do seu perfil do chrome 
#EXEMPLO: C:\\Users\\NOME_DO_SEU_PC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Eu implementei o código que me mandou mas parece que ele ainda pede para efetuar login caso eu feche o robô e rode novamente o script.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver meu problema, para quem estiver com o mesmo eu achei a solução que para a minha necessidade resolveu, nessa resposta aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/484337/4598